# Create json array from data elements of spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to JSON and I am trying to create a json array that I can send to a php file to process. I want the json to look similar to below.

```
{"clubs":[
{"number":"12", "type":"break"}, 
{"number":"4", "type":"group"}, 
{"number":"87", "type":"tring"},
{"number":"7", "type":"samestuff"}
]}
```

I can get the elements into one array but it comes out like this:
 type:break,number:12,type:group,number:4,type:tring,number:87,type:samestuff,number:7

Can anybody fix this so it creates a json array of the numbers/types? I have attached my current code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#testbutton").click(function() {
            var clubs = [];
            $(".spanme").each(function() {
            var myarray = [];
            var type = $(this).data("type");
            myarray.push("type:"+type);
            var number = $(this).data("number");
            myarray.push("number:"+number);
            clubs.push(myarray);
            });
        console.log(clubs)
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="testbutton">Test button</button>
<span class="spanme" data-number="12" data-type="break">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="4" data-type="group">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="87" data-type="tring">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="7" data-type="samestuff">span </span><br/>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` to get all the span with common class & use `map` which will return an array. Using spread `...` will allow to use array methods like `map`.Get the `data` attribute by using `getAttribute`

```js
var x = [...document.querySelectorAll('.spanme')].map(function(item) {
  return {
    "numbers": item.getAttribute('data-number'),
    "type": item.getAttribute('data-type')
  }

})

var someObj = {
  "clubs": x

}
console.log(someObj)
```

```html
<button id="testbutton">Test button</button>
<span class="spanme" data-number="12" data-type="break">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="4" data-type="group">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="87" data-type="tring">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="7" data-type="samestuff">span </span><br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map the elements into objects for the results.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testbutton").click(function() {
    var result = {
      clubs: $('.spanme').map(function(){
        return { number: this.getAttribute('data-number'), type: this.getAttribute('data-type') };
      }).get()
    };
    
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="testbutton">Test button</button>
<span class="spanme" data-number="12" data-type="break">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="4" data-type="group">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="87" data-type="tring">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="7" data-type="samestuff">span </span><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `push` data into an array `clubs`. So, first create an `object` with `clubs` key and push your value in form of an object to this array. You can create an object using `{}`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#testbutton").click(function() {
    var obj = {'clubs': []};
    $(".spanme").each(function() {
      var type = $(this).data("type");
      var number = $(this).data("number");
      obj.clubs.push({type, number});
    });
    console.log(obj)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="testbutton">Test button</button>
<span class="spanme" data-number="12" data-type="break">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="4" data-type="group">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="87" data-type="tring">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="7" data-type="samestuff">span </span><br/>
```

Alternatively, you can use `map()` which return an array.

```js
$("#testbutton").click(function() {
  var obj = { clubs: $('.spanme').map(function(){
      return {type : $(this).data("type") , number : $(this).data("number")};
    }).get()};
  console.log(obj)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="testbutton">Test button</button>
<span class="spanme" data-number="12" data-type="break">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="4" data-type="group">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="87" data-type="tring">span </span>
<span class="spanme" data-number="7" data-type="samestuff">span </span><br/>
```